# Why is the total average showing instead of category average in my Power BI table?

Tags: powerbi, dax, average, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI I am trying to get an average per category, but all I get is the total average over all categories.

I have an Many-to-Many relationship between Categories and Products:

`Category -1---N-> Category_to_Product <-N---1- Product`

What I want to achieve is to get a visualisation-table with all categories and the average product prize per category.

- I modelled the relationships between those tables like mentioned above.
- I the report view I selected the "Table"-Visual and selected the category name, the product id, and the product prize (for the prize I selected the average implicit measure)

After the two steps above I have the following table:

| categoryName | productId | productPrize(Average) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IT | 1 | 6.0 |
| Household | 2 | 2.0 |
| Household | 3 | 4.0 |
|  |  |  |
| TOTAL |  | 4.0 |

So far so good, that was what I expected. The total shows me the average over all categories.

Next I am doing the following steps:

- I remove productId from the visual so the categories get merged

The result from the step is this table:

| categoryName | productPrize(Average) |
| --- | --- |
| IT | 4.0 |
| Household | 4.0 |
|  |  |
| TOTAL | 4.0 |

In this table the average per category equals the total average over all categories. I was expecting the to see the average per category.

I looked at some examples, but they had a different setting. They had all the categories and product prizes in one Model. I have different Models that are connected via relationships.

Since I am new to Power BI, I don't know if I did something wrong.
I want to to see the average per category, but I can' make it work.

Hoping for some help from the community :)

Greetings,
Dominik

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/relationships-many-to-many#relate-many-to-many-dimensions … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/relationships-bidirectional-filtering

Comment: @Anonymous 
Thank you for the Links, they were helpful and I understood my problem